# Windows 10 Errors Out Loading Kiosk Mode Application with Code 0x80073CF9

Tags: xml, windows-10, kiosk-mode

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, build #18362.1016, version 1903

One of the requirements for a project I'm contributing to for work is that the application we're developing (an application manager used to provide real time metrics and open other applications) can be run in Kiosk Mode on Windows 10. I have been following along to [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps) from Microsoft in order to complete this process, which is roughly, to:

1. Build a configuration XML file
2. Construct a provisioning package using that XML file.
3. Applying that provisioning package to the target device.

What follows is the configuration XML file that I wrote for this Kiosk Mode setup. According to this [XML reference from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-xml#kiosk-only-sample-xml) the syntax and contents of my file seem to be correct. I am referring to the installed application's Application User Model ID and the configuration refers to a new local non-administrator user on the operating system, which when signed in, will act as the kiosk account.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AssignedAccessConfiguration
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config"
    xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"
>
    <Profiles>
        <Profile Id="{2d06cbf5-a2fd-405c-a957-10203ea522e3}">
            <KioskModeApp AppUserModelId="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\TAM\Tam.exe" />
        </Profile>
    </Profiles>
    <Configs>
        <Config>
            <Account>gabriel-local</Account>
            <DefaultProfile Id="{2d06cbf5-a2fd-405c-a957-10203ea522e3}" />
        </Config>
    </Configs>
</AssignedAccessConfiguration>
```

After building the provisioning package using Windows Configuration Designer, I loaded the package onto a USB drive and was able to successfully apply the provisioning package onto a target device. After logging out of the current account however, and attempting to enter the Kiosk Mode account, the operating system rendered a blue error screen with a message saying that Windows could not open the application successfully along with an error code of 0x80073CF9.

I have also checked the Event Viewer for any errors that might have occurred during this process (under the Applications And Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Assigned Access and Applications And Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > DeviceManagement-Enterprise-Diagnostics-Provider nodes) and saw one error under the Assigned Access > Operational node which stated:

"onecoreuap\base\embedded\sys\lockdown\runtime\worker\enrollmentenginewrapper.cpp(77), hr = 0x80070002, message = The system cannot find the file specified.

In reference to not being able to find the file, I'm not sure if this refers to the program I'm trying to run. I've provided the AUMID correctly for the program and that same error came up when trying to provision the XML file pointing towards the AUMID of Microsoft Edge.

By removing the provisioning package temporarily and logging into that new user account, I was able to confirm that the application could be opened from within it. I have also tried to configure the XML file to open a more standard Windows application (Microsoft Edge), and after rebuilding the provsioning package, installing it onto the OS, and trying to open the Kiosk Mode account, I encountered the same error. After scouring pretty deep into search results on this error code, the only results I could really find referred to Windows users who were having trouble installing or updating programs from the Windows Store. I am aware that Microsoft error codes can refer to different problem sources, but I am having trouble at this point finding any more leads to help with this issue and any help would be appreciated.